# Exclude regular expression match if it contains a string

Tags: regex, url

I'm still learning regular expressions and I seem to be stuck.

I wanted to write a reg exp that matches URL paths like these that contain "bulk":

```
/bulk-category_one/product
/another-category/bulk-product
```

to only get the product pages, but not the category pages like:

```
/bulk-category_one/
/another-category/
```

So I came up with:

```
[/].*(bulk).*[/].+|[/].*[/].*(bulk).*
```

But there's pagination, so when I put the reg exp in Google Analytics, I'm finding stuff like:

```
/bulk-category/_/showAll/1/
```

All of them have

```
/_/
```

and I don't want any URL paths that contain

```
/_/
```

and I can't figure out how to exclude them.

Comment: What you are trying to do is really a "second level" of filtering per se. You can get around this by more-fully specifying your URL structure in the pattern.

Comment: So what exactly are you looking for? A regular expression that matches any absolute path that does not contain `bulk` in any of its segments?

Comment: @Karolis D, Please give some basic input and o/p expected... then we can confirm if there is any issue with the RegEx, I am still not clear where you are getting this `/bulk-category/_/showAll/1/` after applying RegeEx, or you want to exclude anything with `/_/`

Answer (score 0):

I would go about it this way:

```
/[^/\s]*bulk[^/]*/[^/\s]+(?!/)|/[^/\s]+/[^/]*bulk[^/\s]*(?!/)
```

first part:

- `/` - match the slash
- `[^/\s]*` - match everything that's not a slash and not a whitespace
- `bulk` - match bulk literally
- `[^/]*` - match everything that's not a slash
- `/` - match the slash
- `[^/\s]+` - match everything that's not a slash and not a whitespace
- `(?!/)` - ensure there is not a slash afterwards (i.e. url has two parts)

The second part is more of the same, but this time 'bulk' is expected in the second part of the url not the first one.

If you need the word 'product' specifically in the second part of the url one more alternative would be required:

```
/[^/\s]*bulk[^/]*/[^/\s]*product[^/\s]*(?!/)|/[^/\s]+/[^/]*bulk[^/\s]*product[^/\s]*(?!/)|/[^/\s]+/[^/]*product[^/\s]*bulk[^/\s]*(?!/)
```

Answer (score -1):

If I apply that simple regex to a file FILE

```
egrep ".*bulk.*product" FILE
```

which contains your examples above, it only matches the 2 lines with `bulk` and `product`. We can, additionally, exclude '/_/':

```
egrep ".*bulk.*product" FILE | egrep -v "/_/"
```

Two invocations are often much more easy to define and to understand, than a big one-fits-all.